# Find.Execute with an array

Tags: c#, ms-word

I am searching through a word document for some keywords using `Find.Execute` but there seem to be a problem when trying to search for the keywords together in an array. Also when trying to repeat the code for each word they don't work together. can anyone suggest a solution for this problem?

```
        object[] words = { "references", "contents","abstract"};
        int foundpages =0;
        wordApp.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting();
        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++ )
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < TotalNumPages; j++)
            {
                wordApp.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting();
                //Console.WriteLine(words[i]);
                if (wordApp.Selection.Find.Execute(words[i],
                false, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, true, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing))
                {
                    foundpages = wordApp.Selection.Range.get_Information(Word.WdInformation.wdActiveEndPageNumber);
                    Console.WriteLine("found word " + words[i] + " at page: " + foundpages);
                }


            }

        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you getting an error?  If not, what is the wrong output?

Comment: Does the Find.Execute works in other parts of the text? *I remember having (compile,link, ...) problem with this function that I solved by using reflection*.

Comment: Tripp Kinetics, no errors the output is the occurrences of the first element in the array only then when it's done with it it increments to the 2nd element but it doesn't enter the if condition also for the 3rd. And I am sure about the existence of these words in the document I am searching

Comment: Graffito, Yes it does work perfectly when searching for a specific word alone not an entire array. I am not sure if it's a compiler or a linker problem I'll try the reflection though